# How to declare array that can store superclass and subclass object in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to create an array that can store super class and subclass objects.

```
   Book[] books = new Book[10]
```

Do i have to use the keyword super or sub ? please clear my doubt.

Thank you

Comment: If you have subclasses of `Book`, you can put them in your `books` array.

Comment: so in your example array - `books` , you wish to store super classes of `Book` as well as sub classes ? Sub classes of `Book` can be put in that array.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume Book is your super class and then your sub class is ->

```
Class SuspenseBook extends Book {
//code...
}
```

Now your array,

```
Book[] books = new Book[10]
```

can store objects of Book as well as SuspenseBook objects.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can store  Subclass object inside a super class array of objects.
Lets say you have this piece of code:

```
class Animal {
    void saySomething() {System.out.print(" Hummmmm!");}
}

class Cow extends Animal {
    protected void saySomething() {System.out.print(" oMooo!");}
}
public class test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.print(" MooYa!");
        Animal [] animals = {new Animal(), new Cow()};
        for( Animal a : animals) {
            a.saySomething();
        }
    }
}
```

This particular piece of code has `Animal[] animals = { new Animal(), new Cow()}` on line number 11.
This code will create an array of the superclass type (i.e `Animal`) and will initialize two objects - one of the superclass and one of the subclass to be stored in the array.
Now since the subclass `Cow` inherits the superclass `Animal` therefore adding the `Cow` class object to the superclass array could be re-written as :
`Animal animals = new Cow();`
This is polymorphism where a superclass reference variable can used to store the address of a subclass object. In short the superclass can take forms of the subclass( book definition).

**Thus to answer you question you can store subclass object inside a superclass array.

Comment: Please format your code as a code block, without the line numbers and with monospacing and syntax highlighting. This can be done by indenting it by 4 spaces.